# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at echo.js:768

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm making a simple chat application, I get this error while connecting to pusher, I'm using laravel 5.4

[image]

Every thing is working fine like pusher and database etc. Due to this error i did not get response

Here is code

```
Echo.join('chatroom').
.listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: i assume Echo is a node_module? have you imported it correctly at the top of your js file ?

Comment: yes it's a node module...